# Global extrema for $\frac{(q^k-1)(q^{k+1}-2q^k+1)}{{q^k}(q-1)(q^{k+1}-1)}$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, wolfram-alpha

Does the function
$$\frac{(q^k-1)(q^{k+1}-2q^k+1)}{{q^k}(q-1)(q^{k+1}-1)}$$
have either a global minimum or a global maximum for $q \geq 5$ and $k \geq 1$?

WolframAlpha is unable to find any.

[WolframAlpha computation for the global minimum](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Minimize%20((q%5Ek%20-%201)(q%5E(k%2B1)%20-%202q%5Ek%20%2B%201))%2F((q%5Ek)(q-1)(q%5E(k%2B1)%20-%201))%20subject%20to%20q%20%3E%3D5,%20k%20%3E%3D%201)

[WolframAlpha computation for the global maximum](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Maximize%20((q%5Ek%20-%201)(q%5E(k%2B1)%20-%202q%5Ek%20%2B%201))%2F((q%5Ek)(q-1)(q%5E(k%2B1)%20-%201))%20subject%20to%20q%20%3E%3D5,%20k%20%3E%3D%201)

Comment: It is possible to prove that the system of inequalities
$$\frac{q-1}{q(q+1)} \leq \frac{(q^k-1)(q^{k+1}-2q^k+1)}{{q^k}(q-1)(q^{k+1}-1)} < \frac{q-2}{q(q-1)}$$
holds, but can we do better than this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can we do better than this?

No, we cannot.

Let $f(k)$ be your function.

Then, we have
$$f'(k)=\frac{ (q-4)q^{2 k + 1} +2 q^{k + 1}  + 2 q^{2 k} - 1}{q^k(q - 1) (q^{k + 1} - 1)^2}\ln q$$
which is positive for $k\ge 1$ and $q\ge 5$.

So, we see that $f(k)$ is increasing for $k\ge 1$.

Since
$$f(1)=\frac{q-1}{{q}(q+1)},\qquad \lim_{k\to\infty}f(k)=\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{(1-\frac{1}{q^k})(1-\frac{2}{q}+\frac{1}{q^{k+1}})}{(q-1)(1-\frac{1}{q^{k+1}})}=\frac{q-2}{q(q-1)}$$
we have
$$\frac{q-1}{{q}(q+1)}\le f(k)\lt \frac{q-2}{q(q-1)}$$

---

**Added** :

Let $f(q)$ be your function.

We get, with some help of WA,
$$f'(q)=\frac{- (q^{k + 1} - k q + k - q) (q^{2k+1}(q-4)+2q^{k+1}+2q^{2k}-1)}{q^{k+1}(q-1)^2(q^{k+1}-1)^2}$$

Here, let
$$g(q):=q^{k + 1} - k q + k - q$$Then,$$g'(q)=(q^k-1)(k+1)\gt 0$$So, $g(q)$ is increasing and $$g(q)\ge g(5)=5^{k + 1} - 4k - 5\gt 0$$

It follows that $f(q)$ is strictly decreasing for $q\ge 5$.

Since $\displaystyle\lim_{q\to\infty}f(q)=0$, we have
$$0\lt f(q)\le f(5)=\frac{(5^k-1)(5^{k+1}-2\cdot 5^k+1)}{4\cdot 5^k(5^{k+1}-1)}\lt \frac{3}{20}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @mathlove!  =)

Comment: Just one more favor, @mathlove:  Can you do a similar analysis for the case when
$$\frac{(q^k-1)(q^{k+1}-2q^k+1)}{{q^k}(q-1)(q^{k+1}-1)}$$
is considered as a function of $q$?

Comment: @Jose Arnaldo Bebita Dris : I've added some explanations.

Comment: My profuse thanks for the additional explanations, @mathlove!  =)