# If $q \neq 5$ or $k \neq 1$, do the following conditions follow?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, inequality, wolfram-alpha

This is a follow-up to [MSE question #2998091](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2998091).

From that question, we were able to get the bounds
$$\frac{q-1}{q(q+1)} = f(1) \leq f(k) < \frac{q-2}{q(q-1)}$$
and
$$0 < f(q) \leq f(5) = \frac{(5^k - 1)(5^{k+1} - 2\cdot{5^k} + 1)}{4\cdot{5^k}(5^{k+1} - 1)},$$
where $f(q,k)$ is the function
$$f(q,k) = \frac{(q^k-1)(q^{k+1}-2q^k+1)}{{q^k}(q-1)(q^{k+1}-1)},$$
defined for $q \geq 5$ and $k \geq 1$.

**Now assume that $q \neq 5$ and $k \neq 1$.**  Solving the (resulting?) inequality
$$\frac{q-1}{q(q+1)} < f(q,k) < \frac{(5^k - 1)(5^{k+1} - 2\cdot{5^k} + 1)}{4\cdot{5^k}(5^{k+1} - 1)}$$
for $q$ and $k$ I get (with some help from [WolframAlpha](http://Reduce[(q-1)/(q(q+1))%20%3C%20(5%5Ek%20-%201)(5%5E(k+1)%20-%202(5%5Ek)%20+%201)/(4(5%5Ek)(5%5E(k+1)%20-%201)),%20%7Bq,%20k%7D,%20Reals])):

> > $$q > 4 \text{ and } k > \frac{\log\bigg(\frac{q}{q-4}\bigg)}{\log(5)}.$$

Since $q \geq 5$ and by assumption, $q \neq 5$, the first inequality could be strengthened to $q > 5$.

> > How about the second inequality?
> >     $$k > \frac{\log\bigg(\frac{q}{q-4}\bigg)}{\log(5)}$$

When $q = 5$, all it says is that $k > 1$.  When $q > 5$, all we could deduce is that
$$\frac{4}{q} < \frac{4}{5} \implies 1 - \frac{4}{q} > \frac{1}{5} \implies \frac{q}{q-4} = \frac{1}{1-\frac{4}{q}} < 5,$$
so that we could only obtain an upper bound of $1$ for
$$\frac{\log\bigg(\frac{q}{q-4}\bigg)}{\log(5)}$$
but not a lower bound.

Indeed, it appears that the inequality
$$k > \frac{\log\bigg(\frac{q}{q-4}\bigg)}{\log(5)} = \log_{5}\bigg(\frac{q}{q-4}\bigg)$$
is trivial, because we have the limit
$$\lim_{q \to \infty}{\log_{5}\bigg(\frac{q}{q-4}\bigg)} = 0$$
whereas we already have $k > 1$, by assumption.

Alternatively, one can perhaps get by
$$\log_{5}\bigg(\frac{q}{q-4}\bigg) < k$$
through [solving for $q$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%20log_5(q%2F(q%20-%204))%20%3C%20k%20for%20q):
$$q > \frac{4\cdot{5^k}}{5^k - 1},$$
from which we get that $q > 5$ if $k = 1$.

**So perhaps the correct assumption would have been
$$\lnot(q = 5 \land k = 1)?$$**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blimey, how could I have missed it!

When $f$ is considered as a function of $k$,
$$f(q,1) = \frac{q-1}{q(q+1)}$$
which when evaluated at $q=5$ equals $2/15$.

When $f$ is considered as a function of $q$,
$$f(5,k) = \frac{(5^k - 1)(5^{k+1} - 2\cdot{5^k} + 1)}{4\cdot{5^k}(5^{k+1} - 1)}$$
which when evaluated at $k=1$ equals $2/15$.

So indeed, in order to have an inequality in-between
$$\frac{q-1}{q(q+1)} = f(q,1) \neq f(5,k) = \frac{(5^k - 1)(5^{k+1} - 2\cdot{5^k} + 1)}{4\cdot{5^k}(5^{k+1} - 1)}$$
it suffices to consider
$$\frac{q-1}{q(q+1)} = f(q,1) < f(5,k) = \frac{(5^k - 1)(5^{k+1} - 2\cdot{5^k} + 1)}{4\cdot{5^k}(5^{k+1} - 1)},$$
which is then equivalent to the condition
$$\lnot(q = 5 \land k = 1) \iff \lnot(q=5) \lor \lnot(k=1) \iff (q > 5) \lor (k > 1).$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that: $$ \neg (p \wedge q ) \Leftrightarrow \neg p \vee \neg  q$$

Comment: Yes, of course I know that @someone. But +1 nonetheless for pointing it out.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't answer your question completely. I actually wanted to post this as a comment, but I guess I don't have that privilege yet, as I'm new here.

Comment: No worries. I perfectly understood. =)